Ошибка при попытке решения дифференциальных уравнений с помощью ode45 (переменная y не определена)
function dydt = myode(t, y)
       dydt = -2 * y;
endfunction

[t, y] = ode45(@myode, [0 600], 1);

plot(t, y);

Пытаюсь решить простое дифф. уравнение с помощью ode45 функции, скрипт возвращает ошибку:
error: 'y' undefined near line 2, column 20
error: called from
    myode at line 2 column 13

Пробовал пример из офф. документации (https://docs.octave.org/v4.2.2/Ordinary-Differential-Equations.html#Ordinary-Differential-Equations) результат тот же.
Я очень озадачен.
P.S. Запускал в среде GNU Octave

Попробуйте заменить endfunction на end

Это не исправило ошибку.
Я вообще примерно понял в чем проблема - если запустить скрипт сразу после запуска среды Octave то все отлично, если попробовать еще раз - ошибка. Видимо это баг, попробую версию для Линукса.

Нашел решение - нужно функцию вынести в отдельный одноименный файл и уже из него вызывать эту функцию.
